# E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists

Tags: ros, sudo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When  I tried  "sudo apt-get update" command I got this error.Can someone help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225649/e:-unable-to-lock-directory-/var/lib/apt/lists/) by [Irene Maria Lalitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/25823/irene-maria-lalitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have either the *Ubuntu Software Center* or *Synaptic* open by any chance? If so, please close it and try again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0